# "Hotdogging" achievement, what are the parameters?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The achievement in question is to summon 3 zombie dogs at once, without using the summon zombie dog skill.

I tried using "Circle of Life", which took a while, but when I finally got 3 dogs, no achievment. I did not even have Summon Zombie dogs on my bars...

I would like to know if anyone knows the parameters of this achievement?
What qualifies for this achievement, and what disqualifies you? Or is it just buggy?

Comment: Is the achievement to have 3 summoned at once, or summon 3 at once? The wording here could make a world of difference.

Comment: No idea. I summoned three, summoning one at a time using "Circle of Life", and it did not count. I do not relish attempting to get three at once from "Circle of Life" (5% chance to summon a dog when an enemy dies within 12 yards).

Comment: I got mine from using the sacrifice rune next of kin, where i just spammed that skill and i got lucky and had 3 dogs spawn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just read that sometimes if you use "summon zombie dogs" at any point during the session (some people claim even having on the bar) then it will bug and disqualify you from the achievement.

I just tested this, removed Summon Zombie dogs from my bar, left game, then resumed game. I just used "Circle of Life" to summon 3 dogs, one at a time, several minutes apart, and it gave me the achievement.

So it seems they do not have to be summoned "at the same time", just exist "at the same time".

The achievement does also appear to be quite buggy.

[edit]
So, in term of what spells/runes qualify for this acheivement, sounds like:

Circle of Life,
Mass Confusion with Devolution rune,
Big Bad Voodoo with Boogie Man rune

And bugs which disqualify you:

There appears to be a bug with summoning them with the Summon spell at any point in the play session?
Possibly with having the spell on your bar? 
Leaving and re-entering game fixes these, or at least did for me.

Answer (score 5):

It's "summon 3 at once". The best setup here is to have Circle Of Life and Next Of Kin. Zombie Handler also helps, but I got the achievement without it.

Round up a large pile of weak enemies and hit Sacrifice. Repeat until victorious.

The best place to do this (and any other achievement than just needs a pile of kills/hits at once, e.g. Like Water) is the Iskatu encounter in ActIV.

Comment: Except, that I continued to search for an answer. One I found was that if you had summon zombie dogs on your bar at any point in your "play session" it would bug, and not give it to you. So I just resumed after removing zombie dogs from my bar, and used the "Cirlce of Life", and nothing else. Summoned 3 dogs, several minutes apart, and now I have it. Weird.

Comment: In that case, I'm happy to chalk it up as 'bugged all to hell'. It might reset the counter at certain times (such as story/act transitions). Who knows.

Answer (score 2):

I took the summon zombie dogs skill off my bar. Then added "Mass Confusion" with the "Devolution" rune (50% chance to summon zombie dog when enemy is killed under effect of "Mass Confusion"). I also picked the passive skill "Circle of Life" (30% chance to summon zombie dog when enemy dies within 12 yards).

I then started a new game on the beginning quest in Act 4, waited until I was surrounded by the shadow mobs - on the first boss of Act 4 - and used "Mass Confusion". Then I killed them all with "Grasp of the Dead".

I got the achievement instantly on my first try.

Answer (score 1):

Mass Confusion w/ the Devolution rune and Big Bad Voodoo w/ the Boogie Man rune will each give you a 50% chance of summoning a zombie dog when you kill an enemy while under it's effects or in the ritual area. Use them in combination with an AOE on a sizable group of (weak) enemies and you should easily get the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this achievement, I had the Summon Zombie Dog skill active, and had used it earlier in that session.  So that apparently does not disqualify you.

Oddly, though, when I got the achievement, I had only two Zombie Dogs alive, so there's probably still some sort of bug here.

Answer (score 0):

I just used "Circle of Life" and "Grasp of the Dead" with "Death of Life" rune. Went to Rakkis Crossing in Act III, got the achievement in 10 seconds. No need for Mass Confusion and Big Bad Voodoo.